# Using Excel, how would I halt execution of a vba script by entering data in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have some vba code to grab information 4 times a minute from a device on it's web configuration page.

I need this to happen from when I place an x in column C and continue until I place an x in column D further down the page. 
I have a function I can call which will tell if an X is in the proper place in d, relative to c.

What I'd like to do is have a button which says ok, be ready to scan. then have it start when the first value is entered in c, then stop when the d value is entered.
I'm also having trouble coming up with a way to enter values while the VBA script is actually running.

Any advice?  Thanks.

Here is the code to check the columns.

```
Public Function BackgroundScan(MonitorSpreadsheet As Boolean) As Boolean
Dim LastStart As Integer
Dim LastStop As Integer

intDebug = 1

Select Case MonitorSpreadsheet
    Case True
        'We are actively testing
        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "we ARE monitoring the spreadsheet."
        'Call scanning routine here
        'Get the status TestingInProgress
        LastStart = FindLastStartRow("SVQ")
        LastStop = FindLastStopRow("SVQ")
        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "LastStart " & LastStart
        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "LastStop " & LastStop
        Select Case LastStart
            Case Is < 20
                'We have not started.
                If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "We have not started."
                BackgroundScan = False
                'Loop around, and check again
            Case Else
                'ok we have started, now check to see if we have stopped.
                Select Case LastStop
                    Case Is < LastStart
                        '**** We ARE testing!!! ****
                        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "We are testing, and haven't finished."
                        BackgroundScan = True
                    Case LastStart
                        'LastStart and LastStop are the same line, we have started AND finished
                        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "We have started AND finished!"
                        BackgroundScan = False
                        'Loop around, and check again
                    Case Else
                        'We have finished testing, and the test spanned multiple rows
                        BackgroundScan = False
                        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "We started on one line, and finished on another."
                End Select
        End Select
    Case False
        'we are not actively testing
        If intDebug = 1 Then MsgBox "We are NOT monitoring the spreadsheet."
        BackgroundScan = False
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error: Boolean variable reports: " & MonitorSpreadsheet
        BackgroundScan = False
End Select
```

End Function

Here is the code which scans the webpage.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Some         As String 'can't resist a good pun!
Dim intDelay     As Integer
Dim intMinDelay  As Integer
Dim i            As Integer
Dim s            As Integer
Dim RunStart     As Date
Dim WhichSVBeam As String
Dim lLen As Integer
Dim CurrentSVID As String
Dim CurrentBeamID As String
Dim PreviousSVID As String
Dim PreviousBeamID As String
Dim ColonLocation As Integer
'*******************************************************
'***             Test Continuous Button              ***
'***         Where n is specified in cell A6         ***
'*******************************************************

'grab the number of minutes between checking values
intMinDelay = GetValues("A7")

RunStart = Now

'Do this until the end of time, or the execution is halted.
Do 'uncomment do when we are sure the DoEvents will work as we expect
    WhichSVBeam = Scan_SVBeam(PreviousSVID, PreviousBeamID)

    If InStr(WhichSVBeam, ":") Then
        lLen = Len(WhichSVBeam)
        ColonLocation = InStr(WhichSVBeam, ":")
        'MsgBox WhichSVBeam & ", " & ColonLocation
        CurrentSVID = Left(WhichSVBeam, ColonLocation - 1)
        'MsgBox CurrentSVID
        CurrentBeamID = Right(WhichSVBeam, lLen - ColonLocation)
        'MsgBox CurrentBeamID
    Else
        'no colon, nothing to parse (this shouldn't happen)
        MsgBox "No ':' from Scan_SVBeam"
    End If

    'Call sCheckExecutionTimeGap(RunStart)
    'loop for the number of minutes we specified
    For i = 1 To intMinDelay
        'check every second for events
        For s = 1 To 240
            Call AppSleep(250)
            DoEvents
        Next s
    Next i
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you currently have.

Comment: Put a `DoEvents` in your loop if you want to process events from the user. I recommend a button for stopping rather than querying the sheet or listening for change events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A example of a piece of code that will run at regular intervals, and allows you to change values in your spreadsheet that will be checked, is the following:

```
Sub testCell()
Dim r1, r2 As Integer
Dim stopIt As Boolean

r1 = doWeStart
r2 = doWeStop(r1)

Debug.Print "The value of cell C1 is now " & [C1].Value
If r1 = 0 Then Debug.Print "We haven't started yet"
If r1 > 0 And r2 = 0 Then Debug.Print "We start but don't stop"
If r1 > 0 And r2 > 0 Then Debug.Print "We started and stopped"

If [C1].Value Like "stop" Or r1 > 0 And r2 > 0 Then stopIt = True Else stopIt = False

If Not stopIt Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "testCell"
End If

End Sub
'
Function doWeStart()
    Dim xrow As Integer
    ' save old selection
    Set r = Selection
    xrow = 0

    ' search for "x" in column C
    On Error Resume Next
    xrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("x", [C:C], 0)
    doWeStart = xrow

End Function
'
Function doWeStop(r1)
    Dim xrowd As Integer
    xrowd = 0

    ' search for "x" in column D, starting at row r1
    On Error Resume Next
    xrowd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("x", Range("D" & r1, "D1048576"), 0)
    If xrowd > 0 Then
        doWeStop = xrowd + r1 - 1
    Else
        doWeStop = 0
    End If

End Function
```

This will run every five seconds, will look for the first "x" in column C and the first "x" in column D below the one found in C. Depending on what is there, it will (for now) print a message in the debug window - you can put your code there. When you enter "stop" in C1, or an "x" is found in both C and D, it stops.

Answer (score 0):

in pseudo code it would be something along th lines of:

```
start when column c=x
    begin loop
        get data
        check value of column d
        if column d= x exit loop
    next loop iteration
end
```

is that what you want?

Philip

Comment: Thanks to you too, Philip!